# Woo-commerce: 2 columns products on mobile is not spaced properly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a woo-commerce website and I'm using oceanwp theme. 
I tried to make the shop on the mobile appears as two columns of products. 
I tried this code.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .woocommerce .cols-2 li.product, .woocommerce .cols-3 li.product, .woocommerce .cols-4 li.product, .woocommerce.columns-2 li.product, .woocommerce.columns-3 li.product, .woocommerce.columns-4 li.product {
    width: 48% !important;
  }
}
```

it worked but some pages have spacing between products(see the image below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3auS.png)

how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .woocommerce .cols-2 li.product, .woocommerce .cols-3 li.product, .woocommerce .cols-4 li.product, .woocommerce.columns-2 li.product, .woocommerce.columns-3 li.product, .woocommerce.columns-4 li.product {
    width: 47% !important;
    float:left!important;
    min-height:295px;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide me url here?

Comment: sure. www.krtc.store

Comment: actually the problem occurs in three pages. The home page and https://krtc.store/shop/new-in-stock/ and this page https://krtc.store/shop/featured-products/

Comment: try adding `min-height` as i added in the above code

Comment: hey if my answer fixed your issue please upvote and accept my answer

Comment: it worked with two pages but one page is still not fixed and I don't know why.

Comment: Which page is not fixed?

Comment: this one krtc.store/shop/featured-products

Comment: after adjusting the numbers, it worked FINALLY. Thannkk you